# How to transform this int list list to a math expression containing + and *?

Tags: ocaml

Given this list :

```
let mylist = [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[6];[7];[8;9]]
```

I need to transform it to : `"1*2*3+4+5+6+7+8*9"`

This is the solution I came up with :

```
 let rec printexpr = function 
 | [] -> ""
 | [x] -> print_inner_list x
 | x::t -> print_inner_list x ^ "+" ^printexpr t

and print_inner_list = function
 | [] -> ""
 | [x] -> string_of_int x
 | x::y -> string_of_int x ^ "*" ^ print_inner_list y
```

I'd like to come up with another solution that is shorter using String.concat and List.concat (if necessary).

My "idea" is to use

```
String.concat "+" mylist
```

So that it "becomes" something like this :

```
[[1;2;3]+[4]+[5]+[6]+[7]+[8;9]]
```

and then call `String.concat "*" on the inner list of length >=2`
so I get this :

`[[1*2*3]+[4]+[5]+[6]+[7]+[8*9]]`

And List.concat to get `1*2*3+4+5+6+7+8*9`
But this is not how string.concat works, so I'm not sure how to implement this

EDIT : NEW SOLUTION

```
let rec convertListToString = function 
| [] -> []
| x::y -> [List.map string_of_int x] @ convertListToString y
 let mylist = [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[6];[7];[8;9]]

let _ = String.concat "+" (List.concat (List.map (fun x -> [String.concat "*" x ]) (convertListToString test)))

(* STEP BY STEP *)
(* [[1; 2; 3]; [4]; [5]; [6]; [7]; [8; 9]] *)

(convertListToString mylist)
(* string list list =
[["1"; "2"; "3"]; ["4"]; ["5"]; ["10"; "11"]; ["6"]; ["7"]; ["8"; "9"]] *)

    List.map (fun x -> [String.concat "*" x ]) (convertListToString mylist);;
    (*  string list list = [["1*2*3"]; ["4"]; ["5"]; ["6"]; ["7"]; ["8*9"]] *)

    (List.concat (List.map (fun x -> [String.concat "*" x ]) (convertListToString mylist)));;
    (* string list = ["1*2*3"; "4"; "5"; "6"; "7"; "8*9"] *)

    String.concat "+" (List.concat (List.map (fun x -> [String.concat "*" x ]) (convertListToString mylist)))
    (* string = "1*2*3+4+5+6+7+8*9" *)
```

EDIT2 : NEW SOLUTION

```
let rec convertListToString = function 
| [] -> []
| x::y -> string_of_int x :: convertListToString y
let mylist = [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[10;11];[6];[7];[8;9]]

let _ = String.concat "+" (List.map (fun x -> String.concat "*" (convertListToString x)) mylist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a function `soi` that changes an int to a string. Then you can use `List.map` to map this function over a list of ints, thus changing a list of ints into a list of strings. So you have a function that changes a list of ints to a list of strings.

If you compose this function with `String.concat` you have a function that changes a list of ints into a string. (You can use `"+"` as your separator.)

If you map this function over your original input, you end up with a list of strings.

So you have a function that changes a list of list of int into a list of string.

If you compose this function with `String.concat` you end up with one string. (You can use `"*"` as your separator.)

Comment: Thank your for your help, I've edited my post to add the new solution. I tried to follow your step but got little bit lost, my solution gives me the right answer but I had to use List.concat even thought you didn't , can my code be improved further ?

Comment: Nevermind sorry, it just clicked after reading it again  ! thank you again

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for printing complex data types is to use the Format module
which has one built-in combinator `pp_print_list` that creates a printer for a list of elements from a printer for one element.

```ml
(* Format names are a bit too verbose *)
let int, list = Format.(pp_print_int, pp_print_list)

(* The separator will be either "+" or "*" *) 
let const x ppf () = Format.fprintf ppf x

let factor ppf l = 
  (* a factor is a list of int separated by a "*" *)
  list ~pp_sep:(const "*") int ppf l

let expr ppf l =
  (*an expression is a list of factors separated by "+"*) 
  list ~pp_sep:(const "+") factor ppf l
```

Then it is possible to use `Format.asprintf` to build a string from this printer:

```ml
let s = Format.asprintf "%a" expr [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[6];[7];[8;9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.concat` to join strings and `List.map` to change the lists into string lists:

```
let mylist = [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[6];[7];[8;9]];;

let f xs =
  String.concat
    "+" 
    (List.map 
      (fun x -> String.concat
        "*" 
        (List.map (fun i -> string_of_int i) x))
      xs);;

# f mylist;;
- : string = "1*2*3+4+5+6+7+8*9"
```

You can also write this using some higher order helper functions:

```
let mylist = [[1;2;3];[4];[5];[6];[7];[8;9]]
let convcat sep conv xs = String.concat sep (List.map conv xs)
let convplus = convcat "+" string_of_int
let convmul = convcat "*" convplus  
let res = convmul mylist;;

val mylist : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [4]; [5]; [6]; [7]; [8; 9]]
val convcat : string -> ('a -> string) -> 'a list -> string = <fun>
val convplus : int list -> string = <fun>
val convmul : int list list -> string = <fun>
val res : string = "1+2+3*4*5*6*7*8+9"
```